# Submiting a form created inside an AJAX response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have 3 steps to do:

1. Send some datas via AJAX to a PHP page
2. Retrieve results and show to user a button with popover which contains a form to save name of user search
3. Send this form in other PHP page via other AJAX

Points 1 and 2 work fine.
I put popover function in 'complete' section of ajax because popover is created only after results are retrieved.

For point 3, i am unable to catch last form with on.submit. When i click on submit button, it sends form (reload my page).

Here is my code:

HTML part:

```
<body>
<div class="row" id="results"></div>
</body>
```

JS part:

```
/* popover form for save search */
var search_box = '<div id="popover-content" class="hide">'+
                    '<form id="searchForm" class="form-inline" role="form">'+
                        '<div class="form-group has-warning">'+
                            '<input placeholder="Name" class="form-control" maxlength="50" type="text"> '+
                            '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>'+                              
                        '</div>'+
                    '</form>'+
                '</div>';

/* function to retrieve results and show button with popover */
function searchresults() {              
    if(select_data !== ''){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "search.php",
            data: { q: select_data },
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                if($.isPlainObject(data) && data.state === 200){
                    // here is code to retrieve results...

                    // show button with popover and form
                    saveButton ='<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-warning btn-lg" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="auto top" data-title="Enter name for your search"><i class="fa fa-star"></i> Save selection</button>'+search_box;
                    $("div#results").html(saveButton);  
                }
            },
            complete: function (jqXHR, status) {
                $("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
                    html: true, 
                    content: function() {
                          return $('#popover-content').html();
                        }
                });

                /* ******** PART DOES NOT WORK ******** */
                $("#searchForm").on('submit', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    alert('passed');
                   /* code ajax here */

                   return false;
                });
            }
        });
    }return false;
}
```

How to correct this?

Comment: Why are you adding the search box to the DOM dynamically? It doesn't contain anything from the AJAX response, so you should be able to put it into the original HTML, hide it with CSS, then show it when the AJAX returns.

Comment: Is it possible that you have multiple elements with `id="searchForm"`? IDs are supposed to be unique, and `$("#searchForm")` will only select the first one.

Comment: No, i have only 1 searchForm.
I have add search box dynamically because it needs to be positionned in div#results, and this DIV is emptied of its contents if user search have no results, with $("div#results").html('');

Comment: It would be better if you had separate DIVs for the results to be displayed and for the search form, so that displaying the results doesn't remove the form.

Comment: @Barmar, yes i put search box in original HTML, and it is shown correctly.
But my problem when submit persists. Where do i have to place my handler $(#searchForm).on('submit', function(e)  ?

Comment: i have the impression that this function of popover duplicate the complete  div 'popover-content' (which contains form). I started with this example : [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/89823). Can you look at this?

Comment: The handler shoud be at the top-level of the `$(document).ready()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add $(document) .... Let me know if it works I didnt test

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form#yourFormID', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   alert('passed');
   /* code ajax here */

   return false;
});
```

Comment: He's binding the handler after the `success` function adds the form to the DOM. He doesn't need to use delegation.

Comment: If you do this, you shouldn't run it in the `complete` callback, you should just run it once in `$(document).ready`. Otherwise you'll get multiple AJAX calls when you submit the form.